# Charge transfer from electrometer to metal ball

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential

I was solving a physics problem wherein an electrometer was charged to certain volts and then it was brought in contact to a neutral metal ball, then metal ball was taken away and earthed. This process was repeated $n$ times , where it was given that $m$ number of processes are required to reduce the potential of electrometer to half. Then how do we evaluate the potential of electrometer after the same process has been done $n$ times?

In the solution they have used half life method, that is, they claim since it takes $m$ number of processes to reduce the potential to half, so potential as a function of $n$ is given by $$V=\dfrac{V_0}{2^{\frac{n}{m}}}$$ where $V_0$ is the initial potential. But how do we know this will be the manner in which charge would get transferred? Couldn't it follow some other relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the capacitance of the electrometer be $C_e$ and that of the ball be $C_b$. If the potential of the electrometer before the ball touches the electrometer for the $n^\text{th}$ time is $V_{n-1}$ and the potential of the electrometer when the ball is in contact for the $n^\text{th}$ time is $V_n$, then since charge is conserved and the ball, while in contact with the electrometer, is at the same potential:
$$C_e\ V_{n-1}= (C_e + C_b)V_n.$$
So
$$\frac{V_n}{V_{n-1}}=\frac{C_e}{C_e + C_b}= \text{constant}$$
From which your result follows easily.